# Paypal always opens in Polish

Tags: ios, paypal

I open an URL in **Safari** with the following link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=XXXXXXXXXX&lc=PL&item_name=Donate%20Field%20Service&amount=\(amount)&currency_code=\(currency)&bn=PP%2dDonationsBF%3abtn_donate_SM%2egif%3aNonHosted
```

My client (from Ukraine) said that it always opens in Polish language. Why? Should not it be in the local language for the browser?

I changed settings of iOS to English language, but the site still opens in Polish.

[image: PayPal in Polish]

In incognito mode, there is still the same:

[image]

Comment: As @the4kman mentioned, the `lc` parameter is the one responsible for suiting the locale :)

Comment: What `currency` is filled in?

Comment: one of `JPY, EUR, GBP`.

Answer (score 5):

The `lc` query is responsible for the localization of the site. Remove `&lc=PL` from the URL.

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=XXXXXXXXXX&item_name=Donate%20Field%20Service&amount=\(amount)&currency_code=\(currency)&bn=PP%2dDonationsBF%3abtn_donate_SM%2egif%3aNonHosted
```

Comment: That's all?:) I will do and let you know...:) Seems as a solution:)

Comment: Hi, still opens in Polish language. Although my iOS lanaguage is english.

Comment: Actually when I open the link in Safari it is redirected to the following link: `https://mobile.paypal.com/pl/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&useraction=commit&token=EC-1J1951623U619254W#m`. Why there is PL?

Comment: Try to erase your caches and view the page in incognito mode. After all, it's possible that PayPal tracks your location from your IP address like Google does.